# Drag and drop of image in Chrome

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, iframe, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to write a script for drag and drop of image in  a  iframe in Chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        function InsertImage(ev)
        {
            alert("drag function called");
            var _image = document.createElement("image");
            var _sel = _win.getSelection();
            if(!_sel.isCollapsed)
            {
                _sel.deleteFromDocument();
            }
            try{
                var _range = _sel.getRangeAt(0);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                _range = _doc.createRange();
                alert("000000:::: "+e);
                alert("_range is ::"+_range);
            }
            if(!_range)
            {
                _range = _doc.createRange();
            }
            alert("range is ::::"+_range);
            try
            {
                _range.insertNode(_image);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert("1111::  "+e);
            } 
            _range.insertNode(_image);


        }

        function init()
        {
            _iframe =   document.createElement("iframe");
            _iframe.id = "view";
            _iframe.style.height = "250px";
            _iframe.style.width = "600px";
            _iframe.style.top =   "20px";
            _iframe.style.left = "200px";
            _iframe.style.position = "absolute";
            _iframe.style.border = "2px solid lightBlue";
            document.body.appendChild(_iframe);
                _iframe.contentDocument.designMode="on";//No I18N
                _win = _iframe.contentWindow;
                _win.focus();
                _doc = _win.document; //making it global variable

                _doc.body.innerHTML = "<p>aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjj kkkk llll mmmm nnnn oooo pppp qqqq rrrr ssss tttt uuuu vvvv wwww xxxx yyyy zzzz</p>";
                _doc.addEventListener("dragover",InsertImage,false);

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:300px;left:100px ">
        <p> this si a testing doc.here, we test the things</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is is not working..
In chrome console , I get this error message:

> Uncaught Error: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: DOM Exception 4

Something wrong with selection and range, i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DOMException.WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR` exception is thrown whenever a DOM manipulation method **tries to work** with nodes that are part of **two different DOMDocuments**. You must use the `DOMDocument.importNode` method in order to **import** a DOMNode from one document to another.

I suppose you have to import the image-node to the iFrame-document

something like (untested):

```
var nodeToImport = _doc.importNode(_image, true);
//nodeToImport can now be added to the second document
 _doc.appendChild(nodeToImport);
```

[more here](http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/website/documentation-w3cdom-DOMDocument.html#DOMDocumentImportNode)

Comment: Thanks Casper, it worked now, the only thing was to i have to use "**_doc.appendChild(nodeToImport);**" at the relevant place..